# perl to hardcode a static value in a field

Tags: perl

I am still learning `perl` and have all most got a program written.  My question, as simple as it may be, is if I want to hardcode a string to a field would the below do that?  Thank you :).

```
$out[45]="VUS";
```

In the other lines I use the below to define the values that are passed into the `$[out], but the one in question is hardcoded and the others come from a split.

```
  my @vals = split/\t/; # this splits the line at tabs
  my @mutations=split/,/,$vals[9]; # splits on comma to create an array of mutations
  my ($gene,$transcript,$exon,$coding,$aa);
  for (@mutations)
  { 
        ($gene,$transcript,$exon,$coding,$aa) = split/\:/; # this takes col AB and splits it at colons
        grep {$transcript eq $_} keys %nms or next;
    }
    my @out=($.,@colsleft,$_,@colsright);
    $out[2]=$gene;
    $out[3]=$nms{$transcript};
    $out[4]=$transcript;
    $out[15]=$coding;
    $out[17]=$aa;
```

Comment: Yep, that's how you assign a string to an array element. As an aside, you said you "have all most got a program written," but you should really be writing only a few lines at a time and testing as you go, not writing a full program all in one go. That makes debugging much easier.

Comment: Did you try it? Did it work? http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Assignment-Operators

Comment: Thank you for the tips and help, I will give it a go tomorrow :). Not sure why the `-1` but I apologize, i'm trying to learn. How could I have asked a better question?

Comment: I downvoted this question, and the reason is because, as the title text for the downvote button says, "this question does not show any research effort". If you had spent 30 seconds researching it, you would have found your answer. See: [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Comment: Thank you very much for your response, I admit I did not put enough effort in and I apologize for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your line of code: `$out[45]="VUS";` is correct in that it is defining that 46th element of the array @out to the string, "VUS". I am trying to understand from your code, however why you would want to do that? Usually, it is better practice to not hardcode if at all possible. You want to make it your goal to make your program as dynamic as possible.

Comment: You mean the 46th element?

Comment: Yeah, I notice that people call them differently. Some people say the 0th element and 45th element, while others would say $out[0] is the first element.

Comment: People that use *0th element* are wrong. Zero isn't an ordinal number. You can say *element 0* and *element 45*

Comment: Okay. I edited the comment to say 46th element. Thank you.